# Can't import class in Karma.js with Typescript, Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have been trying to get Karma.js working with my very basic test suite. The site works in a browser so the code itself is fine. I have had a few issues but this one I cant solve even after hours of effort. This is my test file - if I uncomment the stuff about store (commented with //TODO), then it crashes, but it will pass ok if I do comment it out, even when i import the Page module. It seems to be only store which causes the crash

```
//TODO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE import { Store } from "../../js/react/utils/store"
import { Page } from "../../js/react/utils/consts"
import { assert } from "chai"

describe('Array', function() {
    it('should start empty', function() {
        var arr = []
        assert.equal(arr.length, 0)
    })
    it('Tests importing Page', () => {
        //TODO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE const default_store = new Store()
        //TODO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE assert(default_store.page == Page.landing)
        assert("__LANDING_PAGE__" == Page.landing)
    })
})
```

This is the error message

```
... all the webpack output saying it compiled ok ...
16 08 2018 21:31:59.648:INFO [karma]: Karma v3.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
16 08 2018 21:31:59.649:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
16 08 2018 21:31:59.688:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
16 08 2018 21:32:00.636:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket KYSAZvAPo7_oibqeAAAA with id 80055480
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Symbol\nat test/unit/store.test.ts:12084:22",
    "str": "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Symbol\nat test/unit/store.test.ts:12084:22"
  }

Finished in 0.086 secs / 0 secs @ 21:32:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
...etc. etc. more npm errors...
```

This is the Store module, its using mobx and their decorators decorators. As mentioned before the page this class is in works fine and is transpiled perfectly fine using the current webpack.config.js, just karma/phantomJS wont work

```
// import * as React from "react";
import { observable, action } from "mobx"
// import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { AVATARS, Page } from "./consts"
import { Bot } from "../models/bot"
import { Message } from "../models/message"
import { WebsocketService } from "./websocket_service"


/*
**  A global store, accessible by any component decorated with
**  @observable
**
*/


//TODO create hover_type here
// Props object for LandingPage
class LandingStore {
    @observable current_hover: "__MENU__" | Bot | null = null
    constructor() {
        this.current_hover = null
    }

    @action set_hover(new_hover: "__MENU__" | Bot | null) {
        this.current_hover = new_hover
    }
}

class ChatWindowStore {
    @observable messages: Array<Message>
    constructor() {
        this.messages = []
    }

    @action msg_in(msg: Message) {
        this.messages.push(msg)
    } // When receiving msgs

//   @computed get size() { return this.messages.length }
//   indexOf(ii: number) { return this.messages[ii] }

}

// Global store
export class Store {

    // websocket connection
    @observable channel = WebsocketService.initialize_channel(this) //this._initializeChannel(this.socket)
    // @observables
    @observable page: Page
    @observable some_global_value: number
    @observable current_bot: Bot
    // Individual stores
    @observable landing_page: LandingStore
    @observable chat_window: ChatWindowStore
    constructor() {
        this.page = Page.landing
        this.some_global_value = 1337
        this.current_bot = new Bot("Captain Moonbeam", AVATARS.CAPTAIN_MOONBEAM)
        this.landing_page = new LandingStore()
        this.chat_window = new ChatWindowStore()
    }

    public static bs() {
        return 1
    }

    // @actions
    @action change_page(newPage: Page) { this.page = newPage }
    @action reset() { this.constructor() } //TODO also delete session & cookies
    @action increment() {
        console.log("CLICKED!")
        this.some_global_value++
    }
    @action change_bot(bot: Bot) {
        this.current_bot = bot
    }
}
```

Here's my karma.conf.ts, please excuse the unnecessary comments I have tried a lot of things including not using webpack to do the transpiling, different browser engines, different file paths, lots of typical debugging stuff

```
module.exports = function(config: any) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['mocha'],
        // basePath: "./",
        files: [
            "test/**/*.ts",
            // "js/app.js"
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            // "js/app.js": ["webpack"],
            // "**/*.tsx": ["webpack"],
            "**/*.ts": ["webpack"]
        },
        plugins : [
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-mocha-reporter',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            // 'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-typescript-preprocessor'
            // 'karma-chai',
            // 'karma-coverage',
        ],
        // typescriptPreprocessor: {
        //  // options passed to the typescript compiler
        //  options: {
        //      sourceMap: false, // (optional) Generates corresponding .map file.
        //      target: 'ES3', // (optional) Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5'
        //      module: 'commonjs', // (optional) Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'
        //      noImplicitAny: true, // (optional) Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
        //      noResolve: true, // (optional) Skip resolution and preprocessing.
        //      removeComments: true, // (optional) Do not emit comments to output.
        //      concatenateOutput: false // (optional) Concatenate and emit output to single file. By default true if module option is omited, otherwise false.
        //  },
        //  // transforming the filenames
        //  // transformPath: function(path) {
        //  //   return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
        //  // }
        // },
        webpack: require('./webpack.config.js'),
        reporters: ["mocha"],
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        // browsers: ["Chrome"],
        // colors: true,
        // logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    });
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")

const config = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "css/app.css"), 
        path.resolve(__dirname, "js/app.js")],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../priv/static"),
        filename: "js/app.js"},
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: ["deps", "node_modules"]
      },
    module: {
        rules:
        [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"] //NOTE loaders are applied last-first
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/app.css"),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "static" }])
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

And here's my tsconfig.js, just for good luck

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true // https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "priv",
    "ts-build",
    "webpack",
    "jest"
  ]
}
```